# Water Fall Logic via use of Update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Data been Hosted in ##YOMASTER  (Temp Table) and I'm using Updates on my Water Fall Logic.

Current Water Fall logic has 3 components and they all share the following: Which ever date is to be used, such Date and its Field Name are then inserted into the following 2 Fields>  StatusCode Location & StartClockDt2 Fields

::: Phase 1:::

```
>  If Date Found on Step 1 then use that date. (Else use Phase 3)
> If No Date found on Step 1 then Move to Step 2 (Else use Phase 3)
> If No Date found on Step 2 then Move to Step 3 (Else use Phase 3)
> If No Date found on Step 3 then Move to Step 4 (Else use Phase 3)
> If No Date found on Step 4 then Move to Step 5 (Else use Phase 3)
> If No Date found on Step 5 then Move to Step 6
```

:::Phase 2:::

```
> If Dates Found on Step 2 and 3 then choose the one with the Max Date
```

:::Phase 3:::

```
> If Step 6 Shows the Max Date out of all other Steps, then Use that Date and apply it to StatusCode Location & StartClockDt2 Fields.
```

Note: the 1st Phase of the  logic its working, I only need query to handle Phase 2 and 3.

Here is the current code been used for 1st Phase.

```
UPDATE ##YOMASTER
SET StatusCodeLocation='No Date',StartClockDt2 = Null

UPDATE ##YOMASTER
SET StatusCodeLocation='Uno', StartClockDt2=Uno
WHERE Uno is not null

UPDATE ##YOMASTER
SET StatusCodeLocation='Dos', StartClockDt2=Dos
WHERE Dos is not null and StartClockDt2 is null

UPDATE ##YOMASTER
SET StatusCodeLocation='Tres', StartClockDt2=Tres
WHERE Tres is not null and StartClockDt2 is null

UPDATE ##YOMASTER
SET StatusCodeLocation='Cuatro', StartClockDt2=Cuatro
WHERE Cuatro is not null and StartClockDt2 is null

UPDATE ##YOMASTER
SET StatusCodeLocation='Cinco', StartClockDt2=Cinco
WHERE Cinco is not null and StartClockDt2 is null

UPDATE ##YOMASTER
SET StatusCodeLocation='Seis', StartClockDt2=Seis
WHERE Seis is not null and StartClockDt2 is null

UPDATE ##YOMASTER
SET StartClockDt2=null
WHERE statuscodelocation='No Date'
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL - Server Management Studio 2008  Version 10.0.4000.0